# Strange outline on points when varying alpha with geom_point()

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the ggplot2 documentation for geom_point(), it mentions that you can use the  *alpha* parameter to control the transparency of points. Here's an example from the diamonds dataset:

```
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price))
d + geom_point(alpha = 1/20)
```

and here's the result of that from the documentation:

[image]

Here's what happens when I try the same code:

[image]

It looks like there's a black outline on each of the points and that alpha is only affecting the transparency of the fill. This isn't the case in the documentation.

Why the difference?

Comment: Are you looking at documentation for ggplot geom_point 2.1.0 ? It looks like your graph. Documentation for geom_point 0.9.3.1 looks like your first graph

Comment: right, I was looking at geom_point 0.9.3.1. That explains that.  I'd still like to know how to get it looking like the first graph though. I know there's a "stroke" parameter but setting it doesn't seem to help me.